# Why isn't Sam Adams Infinium being produced anymore?

Tags: specialty-beers

I had [Sam Adams Infinium](http://www.samueladams.com/craft-beers/infinium) first back in the fall of 2011. It was promoted to beer club members by my local distributor as being a first-come first-serve limited batch with a restriction on the number of bottles sold per customer. It was, and still is to this date, the best beer I had ever had.
Since then I have not seen it anywhere, and their site gives no information as to when it will be back.

I'm curious if anyone knows anything about the availability changing, or when it will be out next.

Comment: I've left a message with Sam Adams (over Twitter). Let's see what they have to say?

Comment: I happen to have a few of this beer, I purchased them back when it came out and have kept them since. I’d be glad to sell you a couple. Though I’ve never have done this I don’t have a clue on how to ship them.
I agree it’s a great beer !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a [response from the Samuel Adams Twitter account](https://twitter.com/SamuelAdamsBeer/status/450629277763899392):

> We brew around 60 different styles a year - sometimes we have to retire some brews to make room for new ones.

So it seems as if this beer is out of production. For good.

Comment: Noooooooooo! This is very disappointing, but at least I got to try it once. Thanks Anthony!

Comment: Nice sleuthing!

Comment: I removed the blatant attempt to sell something on this question.